# Dataset enumeration (epoch and batchSize) when implementing Ray.Tune PBT hyperparameter optimization

Tags: python, pytorch, hyperparameters, ray

This is my first time trying to use Ray.Tune for hyperparameter optimization. I am confused as to where in the Ray code I should initialize the dataset as well as where to put the for-loops for defining the epoch and enumerating the dataset batches.

### Background

In my normal training script, I follow several steps:
1. Parse the model options,
2. Initialize the dataset,
3. Create and initialize the model,
4. For-loop for progressing through the epochs,
5. Nested for-loop for enumerating the dataset batches

The Ray.Tune documentation says that when defining the Trainable class object, that I really only need _setup, _train, _save, and _restore. As I understand it, the _train() is for a single iteration and increments the training_iteration automatically. Given that the dataset_size may not be cleanly divisible by the batchSize, I calculate the total_steps as the training progresses. If I understand it right, my total_steps will not be equal to training_iteration. This is important because the number of steps is supposed to be used to determine when to evaluate the worker.

I also do not want to instantiate the dataset for each worker individually. Ray should instantiate the dataset once, and then the workers can access the data via shared memory.

### Original train.py code

```py
self.opt = TrainOptions().parse()
data_loader = CreateDataLoader(self.opt)
self.dataset = data_loader.load_data()
self.dataset_size = len(data_loader)

total_steps = 0
counter = 0
for epoch in range(self.opt.starting_epoch, self.opt.niter + self.opt.niter_decay + 1):
    for i, data in enumerate(self.dataset):
        total_steps += self.opt.batchSize if i<len(self.dataset) else (self.dataset_size * (epoch + 1)) - total_steps
        counter += 1
        self.model.set_input(data, self.opt)
        self.model.optimizeD()
        if counter % self.opt.critic_iters == 0:
            self.model.optimizeG()
```

Comment: Can you provide more context on not "instantiate the dataset for each worker individually"? Have you tried putting it into Plasma?

Answer (score 0):

The `training_iteration` is just a logical unit of training. It would not be a problem to use one epoch per "training_iteration".